# Display a simple message if no matched result with autocomplete

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, autocomplete, typeahead

I'm working with the typeahead for Bootstrap 3.
I'm trying to put inside the dropdown a simple text message "No Match Found", i used the highlighter function, but i can't get this message i will see always my items even if there is no matched result.

```
function setAutocomplete(){
    $(".autocomplete").typeahead({
        items: 12,
        source: function (request, response) {            
            $.ajax({
                url: $(".autocomplete").attr("data-url"),
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { query: request },
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    if(data && data != "") {
                        return response(data);
                    }
                    else {
                        var result = ['no result matched'];
                        console.log(result);
                        return response(result);
                    }
                }
            });
          }
    });
}
```

Comment: Any idea guys ? With the console.log i can see the data or the message "no result matched" but the result var is not pushed, why ?

Comment: are you sure it goes into the else condition?